# How do I change button background and text color?

Tags: android

How do I change button background and text color in Android?
Unable to use Attributes of android.

Comment: you should post your xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than in XML you can also set color in class editor file like:

```
TextView.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#hexadecimal value"));
```

for Button:

```
Button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(“Hexadecimal value”));
```

Answer (score 0):

In XML:

```
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
```

Programmatically:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
button.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
```